# Quasi-finite surjective holomorphic map is proper?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected complex manifolds. Let
$f:X \to Y$ be a **surjective** holomorphic map such that pre-image of every $y \in Y$ is a finite set.

Then can we say that $f$ is a proper map? I feel that this is not true but I am unable to think of a counterexample.

If not counterexample, hints towards $f$ is proper are welcome!

Comment: Let $Y = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, and $f(z) = z^2$. For what $X$ is $f$ proper, and for what isn't it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. It’s easy but I couldn’t think of this. If $X= \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, then $f$ is proper. If $X$ is a proper sub domain of $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ such that $f$ is surjective, then $f$ is not proper, e.g. $X =$ union of first three quadrants.

Comment: Yes. If $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is a boundary point of $X$, then the preimage of a compact neighbourhood of $z_0^2$ isn't compact, hence $f$ isn't proper unless $X = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can award bounty points to you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a map need not be proper. A simple example is given by the map $f \colon z \mapsto z^2$ with $Y = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $X$ any connected open subset of $Y$ such that $f(X) = Y$. Standard choices for $X$ are $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ or a three-quarter plane. A maximal $X$ is for example $Y \setminus \{1\}$.

Then if $z_0$ is a boundary point of $X$ in $Y$, the preimage of a compact neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$ isn't compact.

Answer (score 1):

Without the surjectivity assumption, a counterexample is the map $f: \bar{B}^c \to B$ given by $z \mapsto 1/z$ where $B$ is the open unit disk in the complex plane.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I found a very interesting counter-example of such mapping in higher dimensions: $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$
defined as
$$
f (x, y) = (x + x^2y, y).
$$

Note that $f$ is surjective and pre-image of any point contains at most two points.

But, $f$ is not proper because for any compact neighborhood $K$ of $(0,0)$, the set $f^{−1}(K)$ is never compact.

Interestingly, we cannot have surjective finite to one holomorphic self-map of $\mathbb{C}$ that is not proper.